# Is it possible to order by substrings in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, version-sort

I have a table called `widgets` that has a string column named `version`.

Data for version is in period-separated string format, similar to semantic versioning. e.g. "1.2.4"

When I do the traditional `ORDER BY widgets.version` then I get the following order

```
+--------------+
|    Widgets   |
+----+---------+
| id | version |
|----|---------|
| 1  | 1.3.2   |  <- This is fine
| 3  | 10.1.2  |  <- This should be last, since 10 > 4
| 2  | 4.5.7   |  <- This should be second, since 4 < 10
+----+---------+
```

How can I update my query so that the order returned is by version pt 1, version pt 2, then version pt 3?

Comment: You can pad the values with leading zero(s) so they would be sortable even if they are stored as strings.

Comment: Thanks—that's surprisingly simple

Comment: Even better than padding with zeros, you "shouldn't" be storing three values as a `'.'` separated list in one varchar field, you "should" be storing each value as an integer in a separate field.

Comment: Mine was a quick throw. Check a_horse_with_no_name's answer. It is the way to go.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - I actually think your proposed solution is better than any answer here; begin by fixing the underlying problem with the model, rather than working around it - Doing so reduces CPU usage, enables indexing, etc, etc.  Which is also why I'd suggest fully normalising the model rather than relying on string encoding.

Comment: @MatBailie, thanks. Here on SO I generally get banned, suggesting "do like this" rather than giving a direct answer :) Mine was only a solution for the given sample set and would fail say when one of the values were 3.12.1 or alike. In real life, I would do it as you said and store major, minor, revision as separate integers (be separate columns or an array ... whatever makes sense in use case).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to convert the version string to an integer array and then sort on that array:

```
select id, 
       version
from widgets
order by string_to_array(version, '.')::int[]
```

Note that this will fail if the version contains non-numeric values.

Comment: Best (and actually the only) solution :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
SELECT
  id,
  split_part(version, '.', 1)::int as major,
  split_part(version, '.', 2)::int as minor,
  split_part(version, '.', 3)::int as patch
FROM
  widgets
ORDER BY major, minor, patch
```

Comment: that's just a matter of using ASC, DESC.

Answer (score -1):

Ugly hack: cast to a network address: (only works for small values, short strings, etc)

```
SELECT * FROM widgets
ORDER BY version::cidr
        ;
```